# Show that $\mu(\{x:f(x)>0\}) > 0 \implies \mu(\{x:f(x)>1/N\}) > 0$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, measurable-functions

[image: question]

---

I'm not sure how to do this problem. I first notice that

$$\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>1/N\} \uparrow \{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>0\}$$

and therefore

$$\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>1/N\}) \uparrow \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>0\})$$

but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Here is my argument:

$$\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>0\})>0 \implies \exists \epsilon>0 \;\;st\;\; \mu(\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>\epsilon\})>0$$

Let $N$ be large enough such that $1/N < \epsilon$.

Is this enough? Does it even make sense?

---

EDIT:

Let $A_n, n\in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\mu(A_n)=0$. Then

$$\mu\left(\bigcup_n A_n\right)\leq \sum_n \mu(A_n) = 0$$

Using this result

$$\{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>0\} = \bigcup_N \{\omega\in\Omega:f(\omega)>1/N\} $$

Leading to a contradiction if all the sets have measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A countable union of sets with measure $0$ has measure $0$ (show this!). How can you apply this here?

Comment: Please check my edit, using your hint. Also is there a reason why my attempt was wrong?

Comment: Your edit solves the problem nicely! I'm not quite sure I understand your previous attempt. What does the upward arrow mean?

Comment: It means "approaches from below" but I didn't use that in my proof. My proof is basically the very last statement, where I say, that there must necessarily be an $\epsilon$ small enough, that is includes that subset of $\{\omega\in \Omega: f(\omega)>0\}$ that results in positive measure.

Answer (score 1):

Your EDIT uses countably additive property, and it goes through.

Your first solution uses the monotonic of sequence, and it actually goes through, as you know that $\lim_{n}a_{n}=L>0$, then for sufficiently large $n$, $a_{n}>0$.